# Office 365 Sent Items folder do not store mails send from swaks command

Tags: linux, email, smtp, office365, nodemailer

I am using office 365 SMTP settings to send mail from ubuntu command line. I am able to send emails without any issues, but I need that sent emails to show in **Sent Items** folder, which it isn't doing.  Is there any option to enable this?

Note: I know, BCC the same mail and set inbound redirection rule to Sent Items folder will work in Office 365. But this is not a proper way. Gmail will save sent mails in Sent Items folder without any redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour with SMTP. Some clients like Gmail are using IMAP to create a copy and save it in the sent folder but it's not possible to do this using only SMTP.